# Prevent click event on row in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In a jqgrid grid, I have a checkbox as first column and some other columns. When I click on the row (everywhere) the checkbox switch to checked or to unchecked.

Could you tell me how "click" event on all row ? I'd like to do this after the grid generation because the grid is created by a framework.

Thanks,

Comment: What you mean with "disabling" of the click on the row? Do you want prevent row selection? Do you want implement your own "onCellClick" event handler?

Comment: I don't want any event when I click on the row

Comment: Sorry, I still not understand what you want. Do you use `multiselect: true` option or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setGridParam` method to register a `beforeSelectRow` event handler on an existing grid. That handler should return `false` to cancel the selection operation.

In your case, you can use the the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method on the [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property of the event in order to determine if the click was initiated on the check box. The end result would be something like:

```
$("#yourGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
    beforeSelectRow: function(rowId, e) {
        return $(e.target).is("input:checkbox");
    }
});
```

Comment: As I said, I don't have access to the code to generate the grid, it's in a framework. I have to prevent click after grid generation

Comment: Indeed, that's why I suggested you use `jqGrid("setGridParam")` instead of registering the handler when creating the grid. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Kris-I: In any way you use jqGrid, so you can open the source code of the page in the web browser or you can look in some JavaScript files included in the page. You will see *how exactly* jqGrid is used, with which parameters it will be used. If you would include the code in the text of your question it would clear many things.