# JqGrid - Prevent checkbox check event on row click and keep row highlight enabled

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with multiselect enabled. But I don't want to check the checkbox when I click on the row.

Using the code snippet

```
$("#yourGrid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
    beforeSelectRow: function(rowId, e) {
       return $(e.target).is("input:checkbox");
    }
});
```

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833301/prevent-click-event-on-row-in-jqgrid) I was able to refrain from selecting the checkbox but now I can't highlight a particular row. How can I enable highlighting of a row keeping multiselect on row click disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property on the grid that should do this for you, according to the [API](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions&s%5B%5D=multiselect).

```
multiboxonly
```

> This option works only when the multiselect option is set to true.
>   When multiselect is set to true, clicking anywhere on a row selects
>   that row; when multiboxonly is also set to true, the multiselection is
>   done only when the checkbox is clicked (Yahoo style). Clicking in any
>   other row (suppose the checkbox is not clicked) deselects all rows and
>   selects the current row.

With this you shouldn't need your `beforeSelectRow` function:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
     . . .
     multiselect: true,
     multiboxonly: true
     . . .
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This option multiboxonly: true still make checkbox checked on row selection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).